# Compass deprecation warning Sass 3.5 no support Ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, sass, compass-sass, compass, grunt-contrib-sass

On my system, when I run `compass -v` or `sass -v`, it outputs deprecation warning:

`Sass 3.5 will no longer support Ruby 1.9.3.`.

Running `ruby -v` gives:

`ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [x86_64-linux]`

compass version is 1.0.3 and sass version is 3.4.22.

What I have done:

- Re-run `gem install compass` to update compass.
- Re-run `gem install sass` to update sass.

What should I do to resolve deprecation warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going to pick an answer but original answer was deleted. So I post here the answer.

To resolve deprecation warning, I had to [install rvm](https://rvm.io/rvm/install) which automatically upgrade ruby to 2.3.0. First, run

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
```

Then run

```
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

to install rvm which also upgrade ruby to latest stable version. After that, however, I chose to upgrade my ruby using `rvm`.

```
rvm install 2.3.1
```

After it successfully upgrade ruby to version 2.3.1, I need to run

```
gem install compass
```

again because somehow `compass` installation was broken. After that, things works smoothly.